# Vue.js Weird thing happens when you store a getter in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, getter

I am Japanese and I am not good at English, sorry.

This is a very simple vue code.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click.once="changeObj">
      Click
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      someObj: {
        someStrItem: 'str'
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getObj () {
      return this.someObj
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeObj () {
      const temp = this.getObj
      console.log(temp) // → { someStrItem: 'newStr' }
      this.someObj.someStrItem = 'newStr'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

What is weird is inside the changeObj function.

I expected that the result of console.log(temp) would be

```
{ someStrItem: 'str' }
```

because

```
this.someObj.someStrItem = 'newStr'
```

I do this after

```
  const temp = this.getObj
  console.log(temp)
```

but the result is

```
{ someStrItem: 'newStr' }
```

I don't know why this happens.

Well I actually don't do such a thing usually.

And, I can anticipate that this happens because I store the getter which returns an object in a variable .

But I don't know the reason.

Why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should `temp` ever be `{ someStrItem: '' }`?

Let's walk through the stages of occurrences:

1. Your component gets instantiated with the `data`:

```js
{
  someObj: {
    someStrItem: 'str'
  }
}
```

2. `getObj` is automatically `computed` as

```js
{
  someStrItem: 'str'
}
```

3. When you call `console.log(temp)` in `changeObj`, `this.getObj` still has the value of

```js
{
  someStrItem: 'str'
}
```

Comment: I expected that the result of console.log(temp) would be

{ someStrItem: 'str' }.

So, same as you say.

Comment: But it is { someStrItem: 'newStr' } . I want to know why this happens.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now. The issue here is actually quite trivial - your code is in fact working as expected. When you `console.log(temp)`, it _does_ output `{ someStrItem: 'str' }`, __but__ because `this.getObj.someStrItem` is _lazily_ evaluated, when you log `temp`, it just outputs `this.getObj` _without_ evaluating anything inside of it. It _just_ outputs the value that is located at the `this.getObj` reference. You can try this out by putting a `debugger` statement right after `console.log(temp)`. This will pause your code execution right there, and it will allow you to see it working!

Comment: `changeObj () {
  const temp = this.getObj;
  console.log(temp);
  debugger;
  this.someObj.someStrItem = 'newStr';
}
`

Comment: Thank you so much. With debugger the result was { someStrItem: "str" }. So you are write. But, "lazily evaluated" is little bit hard thing to understand for me...(T_T)

Comment: Take this for example: `const obj = {}; obj.obj = obj`. It would be impossible to `console.log` `obj` all the way through its nested properties - it references it itself so the "actual" output would be infinitely deep. Instead, the when you `console.log(obj)`, the browser would _just_ print out `obj`, and _only if_ you want to access `obj.obj` will the browser then evaluate `obj.obj` to be displayed, and so on an so forth